# i want write string to top of the file . but it dosen't work.(in c)

Tags: c, linux, printf, fopen, ping

i want write result of 'ping'.

first, i write command line, and then ..write the rest of ping result.

like this.

**ping -c5 -W1 192.168.30.52**
PING 192.168.30.52 (192.168.30.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.368 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.408 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.400 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.393 ms

--- 192.168.30.52 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3996ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.368/0.392/0.408/0.018 ms

but this source result is... command line is wrote end of the file..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define FILE_NAME "ping.txt" 
#define doSystem system

void main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char cmdBuf[256], fileBuf[256], buffer[256];
    char dst_addr[124] = "192.168.30.52";
    struct in_addr ipaddr;

    ssize_t read;
    size_t len = 0;

    if( !inet_aton(dst_addr, &ipaddr) ) {
        printf("invalid ip address\n");
    } else {
        sprintf(cmdBuf, "ping -c5 -W1 %s > %s", dst_addr, FILE_NAME );
        fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a+");
        fprintf(fp , "ping -c5 -W1 %s\n", dst_addr);
        doSystem(cmdBuf);

        fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
        while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp)) {
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

this result is

PING 192.168.30.52 (192.168.30.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.368 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.408 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.400 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.30.52: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.393 ms

--- 192.168.30.52 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3996ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.368/0.392/0.408/0.018 ms
**ping -c5 -W1 192.168.30.52**

how can i fix it???/?

Comment: By creating a new file, writing the new line first, then appending the rest of the old file. Finally rename new to old. Said that: it is a bad idea; log files are always appended, not rewritten.

Comment: Try adding a fclose just before you do a call to "doSystem".

Comment: create a temp file and write all the latest ping result to that file and then append the old file data to the temp file and then  delete old file and rename the temp file name to old file name ..

Comment: i just already tried to fclose before "doSystem". but dosen't working.!

Comment: Try ">>" instead ">" in the command which you are creating in cmdBuf

Comment: @Olaf, Ankur did you even read the question? The title is a bit misleading but reading the question clarifies other wise.

Comment: why this question put on hold?! T_T is anything wrong about that..??.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sprintf(cmdBuf, "ping -c5 -W1 %s >> %s", dst_addr, FILE_NAME );
fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
fprintf(fp , "ping -c5 -W1 %s\n", dst_addr);
fclose(fp);
doSystem(cmdBuf);
```

i fiexd like this.

it works !

thanks to all of comments!

Comment: For future readers, what happened before: as you forgot to close the file, the first line was buffered, the `>` wrote at the beginning, and at program end, the *first* line was finally flushed. Now, you correctly open with "w" mode to erase an eventual previous content, close the file and correctly append (with `>>`) at end of file.

Comment: Unrelated: `void main()` is deprecated for decades (should be `int main` and should return value to environment), and it is good practive to always close the streams you open...

Answer (score 0):

Output to files is fully buffered. You need to flush the buffer before you execute the command.

```
    sprintf(cmdBuf, "ping -c5 -W1 %s > %s", dst_addr, FILE_NAME );
    fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a+");
    fprintf(fp , "ping -c5 -W1 %s\n", dst_addr);
    fflush(fp);
    doSystem(cmdBuf);
```

Answer (score -1):

in sprintf,  > replacing file contents(same as "w" mode). use of >> is same as "a" mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define FILE_NAME "ping.txt" 
#define doSystem system

void main(void)
{
        FILE *fp;
        char cmdBuf[256], fileBuf[256], buffer[256];
        char dst_addr[124] = "192.168.0.6";
        struct in_addr ipaddr;

        ssize_t read;
        size_t len = 0;

        if( !inet_aton(dst_addr, &ipaddr) ) 
        {
                printf("invalid ip address\n");
        }
        else 
        {
           sprintf(cmdBuf, "ping -c5 -W1 %s >> %s", dst_addr, FILE_NAME );
                fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a+");
                fprintf(fp , "ping -c5 -W1 %s\n", dst_addr);
                fclose(fp);
                doSystem(cmdBuf);
        }    
}
```